# How to handle Postgres' VARBIT type in JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, bit-manipulation

I have a table with a field of `varbit` PostgreSQL type.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id SERIAL CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    my_bitset varbit
);
```

I would like to insert/update/query this field from Hibernate/JDBC. I defined the field as java.util.BitSet, since that's the closest I could find to a bitstring in java. (But this is not important, it can byte[] or whatever.)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyTableEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private BitSet myBitset;

}
```

I was able to manage to extract the `varbit` typed myBitset value from the database as String, with a custom AttributeConverter

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class BitSetConverter implements AttributeConverter<BitSet, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(BitSet attribute) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("I don't know how.");
    }

    @Override
    public BitSet convertToEntityAttribute(String bitString) {
        if (bitString == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(bitString.length());
        final char[] charArray = bitString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            if (charArray[i] == '1') {
                bitSet.set(i);
            }
        }
        return bitSet;
    }

}
```

**Any idea how to insert a `varbit` with JDBC / Hibernate into PostreSQL?**

P.S.: *I have long bitstrings (3000+ length), so saving as Int or Long is out of the question!*

Comment: Not sure it helps, but Postgresql forums have some discussions on the problems handling it in JDBC: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/892 and https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/908. Just glancing, you'll want to make sure you are using a driver with support, and probably have to use the setObject(int, "stringVal", Types.OTHER) api on the statement to get it in. I don't think the normal Hibernate converters will work as they will likely treat it as a string on the in and out, when you need it treated as a string when read but an object Types.OTHER when writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321281/how-to-handle-postgres-varbit-type-in-jpa#comment134591975_76321281) from [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496099/chris).

**Solution**

A custom JavaType for Hibernate:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.BitSet;
import org.hibernate.SharedSessionContract;
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLPGObjectJdbcType;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.WrapperOptions;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractClassJavaType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutabilityPlan;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcTypeIndicators;

public class BitSetJavaType extends AbstractClassJavaType<BitSet> {

    public static final BitSetJavaType INSTANCE = new BitSetJavaType();

    private BitSetJavaType() {
        super(BitSet.class);
    }

    @Override
    public MutabilityPlan<BitSet> getMutabilityPlan() {
        return new MutabilityPlan<>() {
            @Override
            public boolean isMutable() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public BitSet deepCopy(BitSet value) {
                if (value == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return (BitSet) value.clone();
            }

            @Override
            public Serializable disassemble(BitSet value, SharedSessionContract session) {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public BitSet assemble(Serializable cached, SharedSessionContract session) {
                return (BitSet) cached;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public JdbcType getRecommendedJdbcType(JdbcTypeIndicators indicators) {
        return new PostgreSQLPGObjectJdbcType("varbit", SqlTypes.OTHER) {
            @Override
            protected <X> X fromString(String string, JavaType<X> javaType, WrapperOptions options) {
                if (string == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return javaType.wrap(BitSetJavaType.this.fromString(string), options);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(BitSet value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(value.get(i) ? '1' : '0');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public BitSet fromString(CharSequence string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String bitString = string.toString();
        final BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(bitString.length());
        final char[] charArray = bitString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            if (charArray[i] == '1') {
                bitSet.set(i);
            }
        }
        return bitSet;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <X> X unwrap(BitSet value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (BitSet.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (X) value;
        }
        if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (X) toString(value);
        }
        if (type.isArray()) {
            if (type.getComponentType() == byte.class) {
                return (X) value.toByteArray();
            }
        }
        throw unknownUnwrap(type);
    }

    public <X> BitSet wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (value instanceof CharSequence) {
            return fromString((CharSequence) value);
        }
        if (value instanceof BitSet) {
            return (BitSet) value;
        }
        throw unknownWrap(value.getClass());
    }

}
```

And registered it via metadata:

```java
public class SqlFunctionMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applyTypes((typeContributions, serviceRegistry) -> typeContributions.contributeJavaType(BitSetJavaType.INSTANCE));
    }

}
```

It works like a charm!

**Docs**

Hibernate's [Case Study example on BitSet](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-bitset) was a big help in the solution.